# Apache2 - Multiple VirtualHosts for Same Domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, virtualhost, apache-2.2

I have an Apache server that I am running on localhost. The root `http://localhost` should go to a VirtualHost application (Joomla!), while I want `http://localhost/test` to go to a second VirtualHost - a simple index.html test file. I believe I want to user mod_rewrite for this, so I have that installed.

I have the following two VirtualHosts defined (I am using Ubuntu 11.04):

Root

```
<VirtualHost localhost>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/joomla
</VirtualHost>
```

Test

```
<VirtualHost localhost>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /srv/test
    ServerPath /test/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(/test/.*) /srv$1
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I go to `http://localhost/test/index.html` or even `http://localhost/test` I get a `404`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: ServerPath is for legacy support of clients that don't send Host headers correctly. Ignoring the technology, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Iain - I am trying to have one process handle all requests to `localhost` and then have a totally separate process running `Mono` to handle `localhost/myapp`. It looks like I can probably do this with `Alias`. Is this the intended way? Is there any way I can do it finer grained, like in a separate VirtualHost?

Comment: You are using mod_mono ?

Comment: @Iain Yes, I am. It looks like it is working with `Alias` but I still figured there would be a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mono project has [extensive documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) on setting this up. In particular they suggest using an Alias directive and a Location block

```
Alias /test "/usr/share/doc/xsp/test"
MonoApplications "/test:/usr/share/doc/xsp/test"
<Location /test>
    SetHandler mono
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 identical virtualhosts defined, they need distinct servernames

Combine your confs into one file (what you probably want) or run them on different ports or give them different names

Comment: I was attempting to do what was described in this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/165732/redirecting-a-specific-url-to-a-different-vhost-in-apache   Do you know anything about that? How would I get that to work? Here is the Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#serverpath

Comment: Note they have the same VirtualPath in that documentation.

Comment: The apache documentation has different ServerNames for each Virtual Host directive, which is how Apache figures out where the request should go (by the Host Header that matches the ServerName). The old ServerPath setting is for when Apache gets an ancient HTTP 1.0 request, no Host Header, so all Virtual Hosts fall in the same domain and a prefix is added to requests to indicate which server the request is supposed to be addressing (this is messy, ancient, and unsupported by almost everything these days).